# Extract row number of array when string searched using Predicate

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode

I am not sure how to ask the question, so perhaps if I say what the issue is someone out there can help.

I have a SQL lite table which I use to populate two arrays: one of names and surnames, and the other array, which gets populated at the same time, of the ID of the person from the database.

I then display these names in a TableView. I use the Predicate method to search for someones name in the original array (called storiesArray).

However, when I select this person to display, it displays the First person in the stories Array.

I have tried getting the row where the search string is found, but this returns a very large number, even though it does find the string (using Predicates as explained).

How can I get the row number of the found string?

So, I have tried the following code:

```
  NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [storiesArray indexOfObject: searchText];
```

But this returns the number 2147483647, which in effect is a -1.

I know that the searchText is in stories array because the following code does return a valid search result:

```
   - (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];

self.searchResult =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[storiesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
}
```

self.searchResult gets populated with the correct string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar Threads here:

[How retrieve an index of an NSArray using a NSPredicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231299/how-retrieve-an-index-of-an-nsarray-using-a-nspredicate)

[how to find the index position of the ARRAY Where NSPredicate pick the value. I use filteredArrayUsingPredicate as filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667615/how-to-find-the-index-position-of-the-array-where-nspredicate-pick-the-value-i)

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/19/searching-arrays-with-nspredicate-and-blocks.html

```
NSUInteger index = [self.myarray indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                 ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                   return [predExists evaluateWithObject:obj];
                 }];
```